# Storing XML response from webservice into Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a custom portal to VMware vCenter through the VMware Orchestrator API.   I am using savon to query the SOAP API (WSDL) of Orchestrator and have that returning valid data... specifically an XML containing all the Virtual Machines.

What is the best/easiest way to capture the response into a Rails Model?   The XML structure of the response is below...

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <findResponse xmlns="http://webservice.vso.dunes.ch">
         <findReturn>
            <totalCount>4</totalCount>
            <elements>
               <item>
                  <type>VC:VirtualMachine</type>
                  <id>vc.demo.local/vm-37</id>
                  <properties>
                     <item>
                        <name>displayName</name>
                        <value>FreeNAS</value>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                        <name>isTemplate</name>
                        <value>false</value>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                        <name>name</name>
                        <value>FreeNAS</value>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                        <name>connectionState</name>
                        <value>connected</value>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                        <name>state</name>
                        <value>poweredOff</value>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                        <name>vimHost</name>
                        <value>https://vc.demo.local:443/sdk</value>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                        <name>id</name>
                        <value>vm-37</value>
                     </item>
                     <item>
                        <name>dunesId</name>
                        <value>vc.demo.local/vm-37</value>
                     </item>
                  </properties>
                  <dunesUri>dunes://service.dunes.ch/CustomSDKObject?id='vc.demo.local/vm-37'&amp;dunesName='VC:VirtualMachine'</dunesUri>
               </item>
               <item>
   ...
               </item>
            </elements>
         </findReturn>
      </findResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pick out the few key attributes that you may want to query for (name, id, type) and then just store the rest of the XML as a clob or varchar or as a native XML type if your db supports it. Them you can read other values out in code when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I use the nokogiri gem to parse xml.  With nokogiri you can call an xpath to get all elements with a certain parent tag. For example using your xml:

```
     your_Model = Your_Model.new
     docs = Nokogiri::XML(your.xml)

     your_Model =  docs.xpath('//item').map do |i|
          {    
                #here you would need to map the objects of the xml to your model attributes so if your attributes were called, itemname, and itemvalue the code would be.
                   itemname => i.xpath('name').inner_text,
                   itemvalue => i.xpath('value').inner_text

          }
      your_Model.save!
```

Make sure you require the Nokogiri gem if you decide to go this route.

Hope it helps